# JSSOR locks up when I upload to GoDaddy

Tags: jquery, jssor

I thoroughly love JSSOR, but having major issues with upload functionality. I checked code, loaded into Google Chrome locally works fine. When I upload the same code to Godaddy, for instance the Introduction Slider with captions, I upload, view and all pictures and captions are garbled up all over the slide and no animation..
Help I have customers waiting for me.

Comment: Please validate the url of js files.

Comment: Of course I validated the url of the js files. With a tech yesterday she told me the spacing, capitols etc act differently on a linux system. Could someone show me an example of how to call the tool-compress locally to compress my HTML files?

Comment: please leave me an url of your page.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's GoDaddy. The engineer of my website software and I agree that they are always changing their code and not keeping up to date with the scripting end of hosting. Here is my site - http://www.travis-websites.com